# Issue with local test environment (Mamp Pro 4) vs Ubuntu 16.04 production server

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

I have finished setting up my website in my local test environment and everything is working as expected. I have set up a GCP (Google Cloud Platform) account with a Compute Engine server running Ubuntu 16.04. I have installed the LAMP stack to the best of my ability (a devops engineer would shed a single tear if he saw my work) and copied over my website by downloading an archive via `wget`. I copied my website to `/var/www/html`, it loads but several plugins I have do not work. These include [WPS Hide Login](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wps-hide-login/) and [Hide my WP](https://codecanyon.net/item/hide-my-wp-amazing-security-plugin-for-wordpress/4177158). Based upon this, I deduced that the issue must either be because of a missing PHP extension or a missing Apache module.

I used this code to list the PHP extensions.

```
<?php 
      echo "<pre>";
      print_r(get_loaded_extensions());
      echo "<pre/>";
 ?>
```

Here is the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Core
    [1] => bcmath
    [2] => calendar
    [3] => com_dotnet
    [4] => ctype
    [5] => date
    [6] => filter
    [7] => hash
    [8] => iconv
    [9] => json
    [10] => mcrypt
    [11] => SPL
    [12] => odbc
    [13] => pcre
    [14] => Reflection
    [15] => session
    [16] => sockets
    [17] => standard
    [18] => mysqlnd
    [19] => tokenizer
    [20] => zip
    [21] => zlib
    [22] => libxml
    [23] => dom
    [24] => PDO
    [25] => pdo_mysql
    [26] => bz2
    [27] => SimpleXML
    [28] => soap
    [29] => xml
    [30] => wddx
    [31] => xmlreader
    [32] => xmlwriter
    [33] => apache2handler
    [34] => openssl
    [35] => curl
    [36] => fileinfo
    [37] => gd
    [38] => mbstring
    [39] => memcache
    [40] => mysqli
    [41] => Phar
    [42] => pdo_sqlite
    [43] => sqlite3
    [44] => exif
    [45] => imagick
)
```

And for Apache modules I issued the command:

```
apache2ctl -M
```

Here is the output:

```
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 mpm_prefork_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 php7_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 socache_shmcb_module (shared)
 ssl_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
```

I am not sure what the problem is, this is just what I think it could be.

Comment: check the error logs, turn on error reporting, this will shed light on any missing extensions.  Also make sure the plugins are turned on in wordpress, if you didn't also migrate the Database.  The plugin configurations and which ones are on is all stored in the DB.

Comment: Thanks, this showed the problem. This led me to enable AllowOverride all in the vhost containing <Directory /var/www/html> and it did the trick. If you will make an answer, I will mark it as the solution. This is a record for the fastest fix on SO!!!

Comment: Sure, that's usually the first step, let PHP tell you what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check the error logs and turn on error reporting if its not on.

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

That will show you if you are missing any extensions, and may shed light on what is going on.

Hope that helps.